# Getting the Text from a Selected Item in a RadioButtonList in a GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to extract the ID from a gridview row but I keep getting the error:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format'.
```

---

Code Snippet:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            RadioButtonList rblAnswer = (RadioButtonList)gvrow.FindControl("rblResult");
            string strAnswer = rblAnswer.SelectedValue;
            int intAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(strAnswer); //error with this line

            Label lblQuestionID = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("lblID");
            string strID = lblQuestionID.Text;
            int intID = Convert.ToInt32(strID);

            Package.Sql.Sql.saveAnswers(Convert.ToInt32(Session["userID"]), intID,  
                                        intAnswer);
        }
```

ASP.NET Snippet:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblResult" runat="server" Width="200px">
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">Strongly Disagree</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="2">Disagree</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="3">Tend to Disagree</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="4">Tend to Agree</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="5">Agree</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="6">Strongly Agree</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Have you verified that "rblResult" returns what you assume it does? Did you check the contents of strAnswer?

Comment: Is the error with Label portion or with the RadioButtonList portion? Also, what is the value of "strAnswer" after

  string strAnswer = rblAnswer.SelectedValue;

Is it a valid integer which can be parsed into an "int"?

Comment: after execution strAnswer = an integer 1,2,3,4,5 or 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After seeing your ASPX code, there's a way to get the text out.  I haven't tested this, but something along these lines ought to work:

```
string strAnswer = String.Empty;
foreach (ListItem item in rblAnswer.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected) 
    {
         strAnswer = item.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't allow me to do that, or even .Text

In debug mode it reads:
  rblAnswer.SelectedValue "1" string

I'm stumped as its a string so should let me convert it

Comment: apologies I misread, just tried: int intAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(rblAnswer.SelectedItem.Value);

but getting: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I ended up using:
            foreach (ListItem item in rblAnswer.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    strAnswer = item.Value;
                }
            }

thank you very much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

What value does rblAnswer.SelectedValue have ? if it cant be converted to a Int32 .. you get that error

So it needs to be an Integer

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you need to be certain of, is the value coming from this line of code:

```
strAnswer = rblAnswer.SelectedValue;
```

Is this a valid integer that can be converted or not?

Comment: The RadioButtonList is set to values of 1,2,3,4,5,6 so can only return those integers:
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblResult" runat="server" Width="200px">
   <asp:ListItem Value="1">Strongly Disagree</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="2">Disagree</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="3">Tend to Disagree</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="4">Tend to Agree</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="5">Agree</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="6">Strongly Agree</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

using Debugging it returns the values as a string which should work but doesn't for a reason

Answer (score 0):

Try using tryparse

int.tryparse(strAnswer, out intAnswer);

this will return false if the string can't be converted.

Answer (score 0):

FindControl returns a null reference if the specified control doesn't exist.

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
{
    RadioButtonList rblAnswer = (RadioButtonList)gvrow.FindControl("rblResult");
    ...
}
```

If GridView1 contains any rows that do not contain a control named rblResult then rblAnswer will be set to null so you need to check that rblAnswer is not null before using it.

If a value has not been selected from the RadioButtonList then SelectedValue will return an empty string.  So, having found the rblResult control you need to check that a value has actually been selected.

```
if(rblAnswer != null)
{
    if(rblAnswer.SelectedValue != string.Empty)
    {
        string strAnswer = rblAnswer.SelectedValue;
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thinking about it, that would give a NullReferenceException not a FormatException.  Has a value definitely been selected?  Perhaps need to add a check that rblAnswer.SelectedValue != string.Empty