# .net listview find if atleast one radiobox selected in eah row

Tags: c#, listview, webforms, radio-button

i have a listview with 2 or more radio button controls in each row of it and i want to findout if atleast one radiobutton selected on submit.

for example

ROW 1 
     Quetison 1
     radiobutton1
     radiobutton2
     radiobutton3

ROW 2
     Quetison 2
     radiobutton1
     radiobutton2
     radiobutton3

on submit i want to findout if user checked atleast one radiobutton on each ROW

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497414/getting-the-text-from-a-selected-item-in-a-radiobuttonlist-in-a-gridview-in-asp-n/1497511#1497511

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for an Asp.Net ListView:

```
foreach(ListViewDataItem myItem in myListView.Items)
{
   RadioButton btn1 = (RadioButton)myItem.FindControl("radiobutton1");
   RadioButton btn2 = (RadioButton)myItem.FindControl("radiobutton2");
   RadioButton btn3 = (RadioButton)myItem.FindControl("radiobutton3");

   bool AtLeastOneChecked = btn1.Checked || btn2.Checked || btn3.Checked; 

}
```

***New approach - not knowing the # of radio buttons***

```
  foreach(ListViewDataItem myItem in myListView.Items)
{
   bool AtLeastOneChecked = false;
   foreach(Control myControl in myItem.Controls)
   {
      try
      {
         RadioButton rdoTemp = (RadioButton)myControl;
         AtLeastOneChecked = rdoTemp.Checked;
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
          // do nothing - this probably wasn't a radio button control and errored out onthe conversion
      }
   }    
}
```

Comment: thanks, this looks promising but my problem is i do not know number of radio buttons. I only know maximum radiobutton count (which is 5)

Comment: it looks like it works even if number of radio buttons diffrent that ones in foreach loop thanks